# Como Pasar un ForeignKey a un template?

Tags: template

alguien me podría por favor orientar tengo una duda vista DetalleAfiliados en donde le doy click y me lleva al afiliado y me muestra los detalles, como hago para mostrar los pagos también en el mismo template

mi Modelo

```
class Afiliado(models.Model):
fecha_afiliacion = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)    
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50)  

class Pago(models.Model):
afiliado = models.ForeignKey(Afiliado, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Quién realizó el Pago?')    
fecha_pago = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) 
monto = models.FloatField(blank=True, null = True)
```

mi url

```
path('afiliado/<int:pk>/', DetalleAfiliados.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Mi vista

```
class DetalleAfiliados(DetailView):
model = Afiliado
template_name = 'detalle_afiliado.html'
```

Mi Template

```
{% block content %}
<strong><h2>{{ afiliado.nombre }} {{ afiliado.apellido }}  ({{ afiliado.documento }}) 
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="/afiliado/{{afiliado.id}}/editar" role="button" >Editar</a></a></h2> </strong> <br/>

<strong>Servicios: </strong> {{ afiliado.servicios.all|join:' - '}}. <br/>
<strong>Pagos:     </strong> 
<br/>   
<br/>
```

{% endblock %}

Lo que no tengo muy claro es como hacer para que en el mismo template también me muestre la lista de pagos, si en mi vista le indico que el modelo es Afiliado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude hacer lo que quería al modificar mi vista de esta manera

```
class DetalleAfiliados(DetailView):
model = Pago  
second_model = Afiliado 
template_name = 'detalle_afiliado.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
     # El pk que pasas a la URL
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    afiliados = Afiliado.objects.filter(id=pk)
    pagos = Pago.objects.filter(afiliado_id=pk)
    return {'afiliados': afiliados, 'pagos': pagos}
```

no se si esta sea la manera mas optima pero me funciono